# Get system property can't work well in the debug log level

Tags: sbt

I would like to get system property from command line and print it in sbt.
I used followiing code snippet

Depend.scala

```
val myVar = Option(System.getProperty("myVar")).getOrElse("default")
```

Build.sbt

```
val showMesg = settingKey[Unit]("Show message")

showMesg := {
  sLog.value.info(myVar)
}
```

It works well when I use following command:

```
sbt -DmyVar=abc compile
[info] abc
```

But if I want to output it in debug log level. It can't get the system property correctly.

```
val showMesg = settingKey[Unit]("Show message")

showMesg := {
  sLog.value.debug(myVar)
}
```

```
sbt -DmyVar=abc compile -debug
[debug] default
```

I just curious why I can't get the property when log level is debug.